# Issues to have content type changed to Json (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, content-type

```
    let data = JSON.stringify({
    "from": "testnumber",
    "to": "testnumber",
    "text": "Test SMS."
});

let XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.withCredentials = false;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
   if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});


xhr.open("POST", "https://thaina.free.beeceptor.com", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json');

xhr.send(data);
```

does not matter the changes I perform the content-type is always text/plain. Do you maybe have any suggestions?

beepceptor test with this code

[image: beepceptor test with this code]

Comment: read the "response" (not the responseText):  console.log(xhr.response), or process the text as console.log( JSON.parse(xhr.responseText) );

Comment: by `the content-type is always text/plain` do you mean what the server sends as a response header? If that's the case, then you can't change what someone else's server sends to you

Comment: If on the other hand you mean the request header, then your code works ... in a browser ... whatever `require("xmlhttprequest")` is, perhaps does not work exactly like browser XMLHttpRequest ... perhaps try `'content-type'` instead of `'Content-type'` - worth a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`node XMLHttpRequest` seems to be a bit buggy

Use `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');`

Then it will work

The code in that module that causes the issue is

```
  if (!headers["Content-Type"]) {
    headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
  }
```

Which adds Content-Type after all headers you've set - since you set `Content-type` this is a different header

The code should've been

```
  if (!headersCase["content-type"]) {
    headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8";
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the complete explanation, if fact what u suggested worked brilliantly!